# Multi project build order in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have two subprojects called `be` and `fe`. I have to call first the `build` task on the `fe` project and then to execute the build of the `be` project that uses the `war` plugin. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `build.gradle` file of `be`, add :

```
evaluationDependsOn(':fe')
```